# Termo "Que nem" está correto?

Tags: gramática

É comum ouvir e falar expressões como:

> Ele fala que nem o pai dele.
>
> Maria trabalha que nem a mãe dela.

Ou seja, o termo "que nem" é usado no lugar de "como".

É correto esse uso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim, é de uso corrente no Brasil, é informal, e é gramatical. Significa "como" ou "igual a". Contudo não fica bonito no Português escrito e formal, a não ser que estejamos reproduzindo a fala de alguém.
Ouvimos com frequência por aqui:

- "Você vai assim? Vestida **que nem** uma mendiga?"
- "Trabalhei **que nem** um desgraçado e não consegui juntar um tostão."
- "Ela fala com forte sotaque, **que nem** meus avós.

Nos três casos acima, "que nem" funciona como uma locução. Não confundir com "que" e "nem" juntos, mas sem terem um significado ídiomático.  Ex: "Eu estava tão ocupado ***que* *nem*** percebi a sua entrada na sala." (neste caso trata-se de "tão + adjetivo + que")

Na frase usada como exemplo pelo OP,  "aquele cão é que nem o meu", **significa igual ou semelhante, totalmente ou em algum aspecto**. Se for só em algum aspecto, virá o complemento a seguir: "aquele cão é que nem o meu, **abana o rabo para todo mundo que chega"** – Centaurus

Comment: Ainda não tou completamente esclarecido acerca do uso do _que nem_ no Brasil. Por exemplo, _aquele cão é que nem o meu_ faz sentido? Em Portugal não se usa o _que nem_ assim, ou pelo menos eu não uso. Mas eu diria qualquer dos teus exemplos, porque podem ser interpretados como uma comparação ao longo duma escala: tão mal vestida como, trabalhei tanto como, tão forte como o dos meus avós. No exemplo do cão, isto não é possível: aquele cão é tão quê como o meu? Grande? Peludo? Bonito? Esta distinção é relevante no Brasil, ou podia-se interpretar a frase como _aquele cão é igualzinho ao meu_?

Comment: "aquele cão é que nem o meu" é utilizado no Brasil sim. É equivalente a "aquele cão é igual ao meu".

Comment: Exatamente como disse o @EmirLima   "aquele cão é que nem o meu", significa igual ou semelhante, totalmente ou em algum aspecto.  Se for só em algum aspecto, virá o complemento a seguir: "aquele cão é que nem o meu, abana o rabo para todo mundo que chega"

Answer (score 15):

O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa diz que está correto: *que nem* significa *como.*

Mas eu compreendo perfeitamente a razão da pergunta: porque razão é que *que nem* haveria de significar *como*? Imagino que originalmente *que nem* significasse *mais que*:

> Maria trabalha que nem a mãe dela (trabalha)

Faz sentido se ambas trabalharem muito: *Maria trabalha (tanto) que nem a mãe dela (trabalha assim).* Em Portugal o *que nem* usa-se quando as duas coisas são em elevado grau: *trabalha que nem um galego* (os imigrantes galegos em Lisboa trabalhavam que se desunhavam), *feio que nem um macaco*. Nestes casos *como* e *mais que* dão no mesmo, já que o objetivo é apenas dizer que a pessoa trabalha muito ou é muito feia.

Comment: *nem que* ou *que nem*?

Comment: _Que nem! Magro que nem um esqueleto, gordo que nem um texugo._

Comment: Revê o teu texto, tens *nem que*.

Comment: _Nem que_ é outra coisa. _Tou tão cansado que nem por mil euros me levantava do sofá._ Ou _Aquele filme deve ser uma m****. Não o iria ver nem que me pagassem._

Comment: Revisto. Que raio de disparate!