# como a expressão "que nem" adquiriu significado de comparação?

Tags: origem

qualquer falante nativo de português já usou essa expressão, não posso falar por outro países mas arrisco dizer que no Brasil essa expressão seja a mais usada quando queremos fazer uma comparação, porém se analisarmos as palavras separadamente faz pouco sentido que "que" + "nem" se transforme em "como".

alguém sabe como isso aconteceu?

Comment: Você deveria dar um exemplo.

Comment: Talvez estejas interessado na pergunta relacionada [o termo "que nem" está correto?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/854/termo-que-nem-est%c3%a1-correto).  Eu sugeri lá uma explicação para a origem, que é basicamente a mesma que a apresentada pelo Stafusa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As fontes que encontro todas apresentam a mesma origem: **elipse de uma hipérbole**, ou seja, uma comparação exagerada, com palavras omitidas. A explicação é bastante verossímil, mas vale notar que não se apresentam evidências históricas (confira, no entanto, a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9229/2764) do Jacinto).

A expressão seria [usada](https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/que-nem-e-que-nem-8216-como-8217-mas-por-que/) também fora do Brasil, e seu uso (com esse sentido) [remontaria](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-nem--como/34087#) pelo menos a meados do século XIX. E ela [é "bom português"](https://www.migalhas.com.br/coluna/gramatigalhas/128718/que-nem), mas provavelmente não a melhor escolha para um texto formal.

O texto de [Sérgio Rodrigues](https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/que-nem-e-que-nem-8216-como-8217-mas-por-que/) a respeito é bastante conciso e claro:

> **‘Que nem’ é que nem ‘como’. Mas por quê?**
> <sup>Por Sérgio Rodrigues Atualizado em 31 jul 2020, 00h47 - Publicado em 5 ago 2015, 11h49 Veja</sup>
>
> “Que nem” é uma expressão informal consagrada, de uso corrente tanto no Brasil quanto em Portugal, “equivalente à conjunção comparativa *como*”, nas palavras do gramático Domingos Paschoal Cegalla.
>
> O Houaiss concorda com ele (que nem todo mundo), oferecendo como exemplo a construção “surdo que nem uma porta”, isto é, “*do mesmo modo* que uma porta, *como* uma porta”. Como se vê, não há dúvida de que “que nem” exprime uma comparação de igualdade.
>
> No entanto, fica bastante claro, quando paramos para analisar a expressão, que ela surgiu como um comparativo de superioridade. “Surdo que nem uma porta” pode ser desdobrado assim: *(tão) surdo que nem uma porta (é tão surda quanto ele)*. Ou seja, “mais surdo do que uma porta”.
>
> E como um comparativo de superioridade acaba se transformando, pelo uso, num indiscutível comparativo de igualdade? Pela ideia de hipérbole, é claro. Estamos falando de uma expressão enfática.
>
> Exemplo: a frase “Meu irmão estudou a vida inteira e fala inglês que nem um nativo” contém, ao pé da letra, um patente exagero: por melhor que seja o inglês do tal sujeito, sabemos que não será *superior* ao de um falante nativo. Mas entendemos que é muito, muito bom.

Comment: Isso foi também o que eu supus na minha reposta a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/854/termo-que-nem-est%c3%a1-correto).

Comment: @Jacinto Interessante. Com a presença da tua resposta àquela pergunta, penso que quase seria o caso de fechar esta aqui como duplicata.

Comment: Dizes "quase seria", portanto queres dizer que não é? Também não me parece que seja. Eu é que na outra respondi a esta, porque achei que fazia sentido naquele contexto. De qualquer modo tenho alguma coisa a acrescentar ao que lá disse e à tua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A visão dos linguistas [Teresa Tavares (2000)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-nem/5129) e [Carlos Rocha (2016)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-nem--como/34087#) é que ***que nem*** começou por significar **’mais que’** (ou ’melhor/pior que’). Uma frase como *comi que nem um abade* (ditote comum em Portugal) originalmente teria subentendido algo como:

> Comi que nem um abade [come tão bem]
> Comi [tão bem] que nem um abade [come assim]

O significado ’mais que’ ainda aparece na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/nem) e no “verbete original” do [Aulete](https://aulete.com.br/nem), mas já não no “atualizado”; aparece também no [Moraes Silva de 1891](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bs44AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA403&dq=%22Que%20nem%20loc%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCzKeRo8H2AhVtxYUKHfITCYIQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Que%20nem%20loc%22&f=false), o dicionário mais antigo em que encontrei a locução.

A generalidade dos exemplos mais antigos que encontrei, a partir de 1835 (ver abaixo), e os que se ouvem ainda hoje em Portugal, são deste tipo. Isto é, o que se quer dizer é que algo/alguém faz muito alguma coisa (*comi que nem um abade* = *comi muito ou muito bem*) ou que tem muito certa qualidade (*magro que nem um espeto* = *muito magro*). Portanto, interpretar *que nem* como ’mais que’ ou ’tanto como’ dá no mesmo: *mais magro que um espeto* ou *tão magro como um espeto* são duas maneiras exageradas de dizer que ele é muito magro. Isto facilitou a **transição semântica de ’mais que’ para ’tanto como’**.

Entretanto surgiram no Brasil usos como “o teclado se toca que nem piano” (exemplo apresentado por um brasileiro no artigo do [Carlos Rocha](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-nem--como/34087#)). Aqui já não é possível compreender o *nem que* subentendendo algo como no exemplo do abade: não se quer dizer *o teclado se toca que nem piano [se toca assim]*, nem isto faria sentido; aqui o significado de *que nem* não é ’mais que’ nem ’tanto como’, mas sim simplesmente ’como, parecido com, da mesma maneira que’.

No exemplos mais antigos que encontrei (indico ano da primeira edição), a interpretação ’mais que’ ou ’tanto como’ (ou ’melhor que’ ou ’tão alguma coisa como’) é geralmente possível, o que nos permite subentender algo para completar o sentido, como indico entre colchetes nos primeiros exemplos:

> fallava o Arabe e Grego quem nem um papagaio ([*O Ecco*, 1835](https://books.google.pt/books?id=R0MrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA563&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20papagaio%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYvI6C1MX2AhUwzoUKHSUdAggQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20papagaio%22&f=false); = *que nem um papagaio fala assim*, não sei se tanto ou se sem tino)
>
> fallava que nem um livro ([Alexandre Herculano, 1844](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tCM2AQAAMAAJ&q=%22que%20nem%20um%22&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik7Y2NmcD2AhXEz4UKHS_fDf04MhDoAXoECAMQAg); = *que nem um livro [fala tanto]*)
>
> levo uma vida que nem um cão ([Feliciano Castilho, 1845](https://books.google.pt/books?id=N7gGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA121&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20c%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw1N2m-8D2AhXqzIUKHYxdCFQQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20c%C3%A3o%22&f=false); = *que nem um cão [leva vida assim]*)
>
> chorava que nem uma creança ([Sebastião de Sá, 1848](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ikNEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA173&dq=%22que%20nem%20uma%20crean%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1nZ2wjcH2AhVBXRoKHccXDHsQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20uma%20crean%C3%A7a%22&f=false); = *que nem um criança [chora tanto]*)
>
> Sonhando que nem um rei ([*Jardim Litterario*, 1849](https://books.google.pt/books?id=jewWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20rei%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiogMnDg8H2AhXD_7sIHbflBwEQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20rei%22&f=false))
>
> Vociferando, agora, que nem um Graccho, e esgrimindo, logo, que nem um Arunte? ([Anónimo, 1851](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fvOuJPibOvsC&pg=PA45&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisnImLmMD2AhWtyYUKHdWbBvE4FBDoAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%22&f=false))
>
> assanhado quem nem um gato bravo ([*Bem Publico*, 1860](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zpdYl0x6jVsC&pg=PA402&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20gato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy17je_sD2AhUxzIUKHVMtCuMQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20gato%22&f=false))
>
> gostava d’aquellas peras rijas, que nem pedras! ([Júlio Dinis, 1867](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zQBnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22que%20nem%20pedras%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBhebXjcP2AhVJCxoKHeTDA-8Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20pedras%22&f=false))
>
> sisuda e séria que nem uma abbadessa de convento ([Júlio Dinis, 1867](https://books.google.pt/books?id=zQBnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA149&dq=%22que%20nem%20uma%20abbadessa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMuq3Vj8P2AhXY_7sIHV_UAwYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20uma%20abbadessa%22&f=false))
>
> Alegrou-se que nem gato com bogalho ([Molliere traduzido, 1871](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mgMaAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22que%20nem%20gato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJysDai8H2AhWQgf0HHWB_D2wQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20gato%22&f=false))
>
> calado que nem um rato ([Dicionário de francês-português, 1874](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Gt43AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA644&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20rato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjtOX_-8D2AhUS14UKHWlqCO0Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20rato%22&f=false))
>
> gorda que nem um texugo […] magra que nem um espeto ([Amédée Achard traduzido, 1877](https://books.google.pt/books?id=iIhFAQAAMAAJ&q=%22que%20nem%20um%20texugo%22&dq=%22que%20nem%20um%20texugo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNzqqd-sD2AhWMNOwKHZfIA6QQ6AF6BAgCEAI))

Comment: Ótima busca de referências antigas!